# User creation during authentication

Tags: authentication, openbsd, useradd

I'm working with OpenBSD 5.6 and the goal is that I need to create user when he or she tries to authenticate with specific password. I've written a script for this purpose and everything goes ok but first attempt (when user is created) fails. Obviously second attempt is ok.
I guess problem is that the system checks username before authentication script running so system doesn't know this user. Is there any way to resolve this?

```
#/bin/sh
# 5th parameter is username
echo "password:"
read pswd
someAuthMethodInvocation $5 $pswd
# check if user authenticated successfully
if [ `echo $?` == 0]; then
    useradd $5
    echo "authorize">$3
    exit 0
fi
```

Comment: Without the script, no one can do more than guess.

Comment: Thomas, script added.

Comment: why do you run `useradd` if the authentication was successful? I would expect the contrary. Besides, 5th parameter is the username, and the rest?
also, are you turning off the ECHO flag of your terminal to read password input without showing the keystrokes?

Comment: Authentication method is just a method (actually, it's a program) that sends request to some auth server and gets true/false response.
Other parameters make no difference to our discussion. I can provide you them:
1: -v;
2: login=yes;
3: -s;
4: login;
5: "some username";
Showing keystrokes is not related to problem - it is just an example script.

Comment: @v.suragin yes, I saw that it is not supposed to be a full script but a cut-down snippet. Anyway my real question is, if your authentication method/program returns 0, it is **normally** interpreted as "everything's fine!", which I would not expect in the case "the user does not exist" (I would expect a non-zero exit status in this case)... therefore I would have expected `ES=$? if [ $ES -ne 0 ]; then useradd...`
BTW, use *[at]username* to refer to a specific user when commenting, otherwise we might not receive notification

Comment: @dave_alcarin thanks for hint. To your question: 0 exit code only means that user credentials are right. It just check them with some values from remote database. So user doesn't exist on the OpenBSD device.